# R - Calculate data frame and assign result to new column

Tags: r

Assume I’ve got some stock data with date and price field. I want to add two new columns to show the margin and determine whether it is rise or fall.

The original data frame is as below:

```
        [, 1]    [, 2]
[1,]    Day 1     10
[2,]    Day 2     12
[3,]    Day 3     8
```

My expectation:

```
        [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]
[1,]    Day 1   10     N/A   N/A
[2,]    Day 2   12      2    rise
[3,]    Day 3   8      -4    fall
```

Here is my code:

```
data["margin"] <- c("");
data["result"] <- c("");

dataDiff   <-   diff(data[,2]);

data  <- data[-1, ];

data[,3] <- dataDiff
apply(data, 1, function(x) {
  x[4] <- ifelse(x[3]>0, “rise”, “fall”)
})

View(data)
```

However, there are two problems with my code.

1. It seems quite inefficient since I’ve to remove the first row (which cannot calculate the margin) by myself.
2. apply() is not working as expected. The result is not assigned to the 4th column of `data`

Can anyone give some help, thank you so much.

Comment: `ifelse` is already vectorised, so no need for `apply` here. Please take a look at my solution below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this (base R only)?

```
df$Diff <- c(NA, diff(df$Value));
df$Trend <- ifelse(df$Diff < 0, "fall", "rise");
df;
#    Day Value Diff Trend
#1 Day 1    10   NA  <NA>
#2 Day 2    12    2  rise
#3 Day 3     8   -4  fall
```

Or `cbind` the new columns to the old `dataframe`:

```
df <- cbind.data.frame(
    df,
    c(NA, diff(df[, 2])),
    ifelse(c(NA, diff(df[, 2])) < 0, "fall", "rise"));
colnames(df) <- NULL;
```

Or use `dplyr` and `magrittr`:

```
library(dplyr);
library(magrittr);

df %>% mutate(
    Diff = c(NA, diff(Value)),
    Trend = ifelse(Diff < 0, "fall", "rise"))
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- cbind.data.frame(
    Day = paste("Day", seq(1:3)),
    Value = c(10, 12, 8))
```